# S3cmd not working in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ubuntu-11.10, s3cmd

I have Installed s3cmd on my machine which is ubuntu 11.10 and when i am trying to download some data from s3 it gives me this error, I have also configure s3cmd with the access keys which i have  (.s3cfg file is there in home folder)

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    An unexpected error has occurred.
  Please report the following lines to:
   s3tools-bugs@lists.sourceforge.net
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Problem: KeyError: 'content-length'
S3cmd:   1.0.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/s3cmd", line 2006, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/s3cmd", line 1950, in main
    cmd_func(args)
  File "/usr/bin/s3cmd", line 513, in cmd_object_get
    response = s3.object_get(uri, dst_stream, start_position = start_position, extra_label = seq_label)
  File "/usr/share/s3cmd/S3/S3.py", line 285, in object_get
    response = self.recv_file(request, stream, labels, start_position)
  File "/usr/share/s3cmd/S3/S3.py", line 691, in recv_file
    size_left = int(response["headers"]["content-length"])
KeyError: 'content-length'

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    An unexpected error has occurred.
    Please report the above lines to:
   s3tools-bugs@lists.sourceforge.net
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Did you report the bug to s3tools-bugs@lists.sourceforge.net ?

Comment: Yes .. I have emailed the issue on this id.

Comment: This also happens with the latest version which is S3cmd: 1.5.0-alpha1

Answer (score 1):

Please try a newer version of s3cmd, such as 1.5.0-alpha2 released last night on the s3tools project on SourceForge or in github.  In this specific case, you are trying to download a 0-length file, which triggers this bug

Comment: Still getting the same error after upgrading the version to S3cmd:1.5.0-alpha2